# HTML Multiple select not returning array

Tags: html, node.js, express

I'm trying to make a web application using express and I'm trying to make a form to create a new product. In there I have multiple select to select the categories for the product.
Here is my code for the multi-select:

```js
<div class="form-group row mb-3">
        <label for="categories" class="col-form-label sol-sm-2">Categories:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select multiple name="product[categories[]]" id="categories" class="form-control">
                <% for (let category of categories) { %>
                <option value="<%= category.id %>">
                    <%= category.name %>
                </option>
                <% } %>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The target is for it to fill in the products.categories field with an array of categories.
But this is what I receive on the server:

```js
{
  product: {
    name: 'Nvidia GeForce RTX 4090',
    price: '1499.99',
    description: 'State-of-the-art GPU. Recently released with unrivalled performance. Take your gaming to the next level!',
    discountedPrice: '',
    stock: '5'
  },
  'product[categories': [ '63a18514fade00e8bc7f4d1c' ]
}
```

It doesn't seem to want to format the array properly and I'm unsure as to why this is.
I've already tried removing the second brackets in the name field to get

```js
product[categories]
```

But then it doesn't return an array when just a single item is selected.

Is there an alternative way of me doing this or should I just use the above and convert it to an array on the server?

Answer (score 1):

It works without extra server-side code if you change the name to

```html
<select multiple name="product[categories]">
```

(without the nested brackets). Then the request

```
GET path?product[categories]=a&product[categories]=b
```

will be parsed into

```
req.query = {"product":{"categories":["a","b"]}}
```

and the request

```
POST path
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

product[categories]=a&product[categories]=b
```

will be parsed into

```
req.body = {"product":{"categories":["a","b"]}}
```

if you use the body-parsing middleware `express.urlencoded({extended: true})` with the `extended: true` option.

Comment: I'm sending it as a post request so it isn't sent through the query, it's send in the body